# SQL Row grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table like (I am omitting unnecessary columns)

```
id:int | name:string | ts:DateTime
```

There are multiple entries. now What I want in my resultset is

```
date:Date  | entries:int
```

e.g. how many entries were made on all dates. actually I gonna make a chart of it. 
What SQL Query I need to use for this ? I can create a view of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT
    DATE(ts) AS date,
    COUNT(*) AS entries
FROM table
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: You are missing a comma in your SQL query. Also, I suggest that you add new lines to your SQL to make it easier to read.

Comment: You query is missing a comma ;)

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one. Fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT ts AS `date`, COUNT(id) AS entries
FROM your_table
GROUP BY ts
```

If you just need date part, then try

```
SELECT DATE(ts) AS `date`, COUNT(id) AS entries
FROM your_table
GROUP BY DATE(ts)
```

Answer (score 0):

To strip off the time part of your timestamps, use `DATE()`.  Sort by the date, ascending to get them in the right order.  Note that this will omit dates for which there are no entries. If you need to fill those in, it becomes somewhat more complicated.

```
SELECT
  DATE(ts) AS date,
  COUNT(*) AS entries
FROM tbl
GROUP BY DATE(ts)
ORDER BY DATE(ts) ASC
```